# Poloniex api 403 error

Tags: poloniex

I am using this code to write a bottrader,in python3 (converted 2to3)
https://pastebin.com/fbkheaRb

except that i have change secret string and post_data string to byte

```
sign = hmac.new(self.Secret.encode("ASCII"), post_data.encode("ASCII"), hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()
```

but getting below error

> urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

have `checked key` and `secret key` multiple time and it is correct
Also deleted the `existing key` and created new
Also relaxed all `IP`

then also got the same problem, please help

Comment: You could use the [`poloniex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/poloniex) package which supports Python 3. Then you don't have to deal with the request authentication details.

Comment: trade = poloniex.Poloniex(apiKey,secretKey);

market_data = trade.returnTicker()["BTC_ETH"];
print(market_data["highestBid"]);
this give me an error 
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: I debugged the code and saw that it returned an html which asks for captcha before it failed. ideally when i have given api, secret key it should not ask for captcha isn't it?

Comment: any pointers will be really helpful, I really need do this? is there any other workaround.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to encode to ASCII, so you may try:

```
sign = hmac.new(self.Secret, post_data, hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19197848)

Comment: Why do you consider my answer as a clarification or a critique, do you double check if I am right or wrong before leaving this comment ? it maybe the solution...

Comment: @A STEFANI-  it isn't about the correctness of the solution; answers should provide a complete and clear explanation of the code; what you have here is pretty much a code only answer with little explanation. Editing it to explain it a bit better would help.